# Delayed rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a preview: https://i.gyazo.com/a010b87de44bb13faa7ba7947df58f8b.mp4

There is a slight delay before showing the page. I am using **componentWillUpdate** method to initialize everything. 
The style of the website go also away when I reload the page (F5). https://i.gyazo.com/dded7ce8dec4e4d7dc85b32a68e3f9b3.png

Is this a common problem that can be fixed? Or have I done something wrong? I dont understand why the page would lose its style by reloading.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      poster: '',
      synopsis: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('database')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState(
          {
            title: response.data.title,
            poster: response.data.poster_path,
            synopsis: response.data.overview,
          })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         render everything
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please share your code, sharing videos and images is just not useful, and if you share code, please add it to the post instead

Comment: @Icepickle thanks for the feedback. I will add the code now.

Comment: theres a slight delay because the assets have not been fully loaded yet.

Comment: @D-reaper Is there a solution? Shouldn't everything be set with "componentWillUpdate" cause its called before rendering?

Comment: @Anonymous The promise isn't resolved before the `render` is called. Maintain a state and add `loading` to the component which is set to `true` when the promise is resolved.

Comment: JS is asynchronous, so I'm not sure that there is a (Good and non-hacky) way to 'block' rendering until all the assets have fully loaded. What I (and many others) would do is do conditional rendering. If the assets havent been fully loaded yet, render some sort of loading page. Once the assets been fully loaded, then render it.

Comment: @D-reaper There is currently no way to do it. Read this discussion over at [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1739).

Comment: @hashcode55 Sure there is, since recently it is possible to use async/await patterns

Comment: @Icepickle It was in reference to "block the render call".

Comment: @hashcode55 The getInialState / props can implement the async await pattern, therefore blocking the rendering

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused as I am very new to the words you guys use. Anyone mind explaining in an easier way for a noob like me? Thanks.

Comment: @Icepickle Read the github issue I linked. Are you arguing that asynchronous means blocking?

Comment: @hashcode55 No you are right, I didn't read that link before :) For me though, it really depends on his architecture. That's not to say it is not doable, I mean, if he really wants to load it only after he got the data, he could do it with an async function, like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/c4qkmgkr/)

Comment: @Icepickle No worries :)  The link you shared is exactly what I suggested in my first comment.